# How do you take a physical drive offline using HP P410i RAID card

Tags: linux, storage, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

How do you take a physical drive offline using HP P410i RAID card ?
Specifically in a  RAID1 array  I want to use hpacucli tool to take a physical drive offline then online to test if RAID1 array recovers...

Comment: LSI does something like this: offline = "C:\RaidCLI\megacli64 pdoffline physdrv["+drive+"] a0" online = "C:\RaidCLI\megacli64 pdonline physdrv["+drive+"] a0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using a controller that supported external storage, you could place one drive in a JBOD and one drive in the server.  Some PDU's are controllable via the network, which would let you remotely kill power to the JBOD and cause the controller to experience a true drive failure.

Since you only have a P410i, though, you don't have a lot of options.  There's no real way to simulate a physical failure like that using software.  There are hardware-based solutions, like [this one](http://www.quarch.com/products/qtl1144.html) that electrically disconnects a drive's SAS lanes to simulate a hotplug.  However, these are likely far too pricey for the limited testing that you are doing.  Your best bet is to physically pull the drive.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pull the disk and reinsert when you're ready to start the rebuild. There's no need to manually offline the drive through the software.

You should approach the testing in a different manner. Run standard burn-in before deploying. Make sure HP agents and management alerts are in place. Keep hot or cold spare disks around. Use RAID 1+0. You do not need to do this for every server you bring online.

Comment: Actually we are trying to automate a test for this. We have quite a lot of drives to test so do not want have someone to do this manually. its a automation issue basically.

Comment: @ndawg don't call a simulation a test! physical drive is physical, when you want to test a failure **let it fail**

Comment: @ndawg - this is not something you need to automate or test. Raid redundancy follows the usual guidelines. You won't be able to do this from software.

Comment: We have all kinds of tests.. this is just an experiment but I agrees it is not a real drive failure. We are just auotmating as much of our drive testing as is possible.

Comment: Also anything can be automated. That is why we are Engineers :-)

Comment: Not this ;) I would use a test system to familiarize the staff with the technology and disk failure/replacement workflow. Smart Array controllers and HP servers operate differently than the LSI/Dell combination.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Let me clarify that this won't simulate a catastrophic failure. This will gracefully remove a disk from an array. As the legendary [E. W. White](https://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite) points out in the comments below, there is no (obvious) programatic way to abruptly remove a drive from an array.

---

You will use the [`hpacucli`](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/) tool with the `remove` command to take a disk out of an array. The command takes the form of `<target> <command> [parameter=value]`. An example command would be `controller slot=2 array A remove`

I suggest perusing the [HP Array Configuration Utility manuals](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00709035.pdf).

Comment: Thanks that appears be what I need to try. Found this doing a: hpacucli help remove target> remove [drives=[#:]#:#,[#:]#:#,[#:]#:#-[#:]#:#]
  Provided the feature is available on the targeted controller, the remove
  command will allow you to remove one or more drives from a specified array.
  The target can be any valid array.

Comment: That command removes the disk from the array. It does not simulate a failure.

Comment: That is fine. We just need remove a pd and then attempt to take it back online.. it is not attempting to pull the drive physically and check a rebuild occurs which I may have incorrectly referred to in my original question. We are trying to see how robust our RAID arrays are. We have done this manually now attempting to automate.

Comment: @ewwhite Won't that be virtually the same effect?

Comment: No. There's no way to programmatically remove a non-spare drive from an HP Smart Array controller. There's the notion of splitting and recombining arrays, but that won't be the same thing as removing a drive. The command posted above deletes a logical drive/array (collection of disks). It won't remove a drive.

Comment: @ewwhite Ah, right. This is too "elegant" to simulate a failure and doesn't gracelessly drop a drive from the array. You could always pay an intern to act as a [chaos monkey](http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2010/12/chaos-monkey-how-netflix-uses.php) and run up and down the aisles, yanking drives out. =)

Comment: hmm I do not want to delete the logical array. Just remove a single physical drive in the array... it seems the command listed had this option:  I can experiment with a little but yes I do not want to delete the entire array.

Comment: That command, when applied to an array, removes spare disks. You'll have to physically pull a disk to start a rebuild. Also, rebuilds start automatically, with no action required on your part.

Comment: hah that is funny it i precisely because we had a intern doing this that he figured out how to automate for LSI RAID card :-).. it actually works. So i am helping do this for a HP P410i RAID card..Yes having someone do this manually is pretty boring and likely make them blow their virtual brains out.